# Bootstrap buttons in Firefox on localhost?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I've got an ASP.NET 4 app being developed and tested against http:// localhost/mysite - I spent a while looking into a problem with Twitter Bootstrap buttons in Firefox (v12.0) where they looked weird.

However I noted that, when testing, if I swapped the URL and changed 'localhost' for my machine's FQDN (e.g. http://mymachine.mydomain.com/mysite) then it worked normally and as expected.

This is kinda good news because it means that there isn't a "bug" as such that I have to fix but I'm curious about why it's happened in the first place.

The weird behaviour is as follows:

The 'button' is marked up as follows (in this case, a `<a>` to look like a button):

```
<p><a class="btn btn-success" href="checkout.aspx"><i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"></i> Checkout</a></p>
```

I also have the same behaviour when using a 'real' button, marked up as follows:

```
<p><input type="submit" name="ctl00$cphMainContent$btnProceedToCustomerDetails" value="Next: Your details" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$cphMainContent$btnProceedToCustomerDetails&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="cphMainContent_btnProceedToCustomerDetails" class="btn btn-primary" /></p>
```

In both cases, the buttons render in a grey, unreadable state and then sort of 'fill up' in green colour when you hover over, until it is about 75% filled up and then stops filling up.

Here's some images

The `<a class="btn btn-success">`

On load (before mouseover)

[image: Button as page loads]

When you put your mouse over it, it fills up with colour from the bottom up in about 0.5 seconds, finishing up looking like this:

[image]

The `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">`

On load (before mouseover)

[image]

After mouseover, again it fills up with colour from bottom up, in about 0.5 seconds, and looks like this:

[image]

Like I say, this only happens when using Firefox, and only when looking at localhost. Other browsers are fine. I am using a freshly downloaded copy of bootstrap.js (downloaded today) with no amendments, I only include one other css file, and even when I don't include it, it's the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem earlier today.  This link:  [twitter bootstrap button changes rendering oddly in firefox and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401270/twitter-bootstrap-button-changes-rendering-oddly-in-firefox-and-chrome) helped me.

In my css, I applied the following:

```
.btn-primary, .btn-danger, .btn-success {    background-image: none;    filter: none;}
```

It worked.  My pages now render correctly in firefox.  Chrome worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of efforts, I was finally able to pin down this issue to a specific CSS-Hack in Twitter Bootstrap.

Removing `*` (asterisk) from `*background-image` of `btn-primary` and other similar classes resolves this issue.

But the problem itself is not in the CSS. It has got to do with the implementation.

For example, I was using AjaxMin to minify and combine CSS and since `*property` is not a valid CSS, Ajaxmin was ignoring it rendering the final CSS without those properties. Buggy button effects being one such side-effect.